# validating user input inside modal popup using jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to validate user input in a jquery UI modal dialog.
Jquery validation plugin is used for validation.

trying to verify validation in popup button click

```
<form id="frm">
    <div>
        <button name="btn" id="btn" type="button" >OpneModal</button>
    <div id="dlg" style="display:none">
        <div>
            Name: <input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName"/>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>


 $(
     function () {
           var rules = {
            txtName: {
                required: true
            }
        };
        var messages = {
            txtName: {
                required: "Please enter name"
            }
        };
       $("#frm").validate({rules:rules, messages:messages});


          $("#btn").click(
              function () {

                  $("#dlg").dialog(
                      {
                          modal: true,
                          buttons: {
                              "Save": function () {
                                alert(  $("#frm").valid());
                              },
                              "Cancel": function () {
                                  $("#dlg").dialog("close");
              }
                          }

                      }
                      );
              }
              );

      });
```

But the validation is always success.

code is in js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aGJrZ/6/

Comment: The HTML in your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aGJrZ/4/) is invalid.  It's missing at least two closing `div` tags: `</div>`.

Comment: @Sparky,Corrected and updated the fiddle and entire code added to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery Validation plugin **requires** that all input elements **must** be contained within a set of `<form></form>` tags.  However, using the DOM inspector, you can see that when your dialog box is constructed, it is outside of the `<form></form>` entirely.

Re-factor the HTML so that the `form` is contained *inside* your dialog...

```
<button name="btn" id="btn" type="button">Open Modal</button>
<div id="dlg" style="display:none">
    <form id="frm">
        <div>
            Name:  <input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/aGJrZ/9/